# Showing that if $a$ and $b$ are real, then the eigenvalues of A...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to:

> Show that if $a$ and $b$ are real, then the eigenvalues of $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ are $a \pm bi$, with corresponding eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}$

What I have so far is:

I multiply $A$ by the corr. eig. vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}a + bi\\b- ai\end{bmatrix}$. They then factor out a $(a+bi)$ , ok I get that for the top entry but not for the bottom because you can't factor out a $(a+ bi)$ on the bottom entry!

They are getting $(a+ bi) \begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ but how? I understand that obviously $(a+bi) * 1  = a+bi$, but $(a+bi) * -i = -ai -bi^2$ which is definitely not the same thing as we had before which was $b-ai$... Am i missing something really stupid here?

Comment: $$(a+bi)(-i) = -ai-bi^2=b-ai$$  More generally, if you didn't know what the factorization should be ahead of time but you *do* know how to divide by complex numbers, then to factor out $a+bi$ you can do this $$b-ai = (a+bi)\frac{b-ai}{a+bi}$$ and then just simplify $\frac{b-ai}{a+bi}$ to get $-i$.

Comment: What you are missing is what $i$ even *is*.  Remember that $i$ is a complex number such that $i^2=-1$.  You have an $i^2$ in your expression, so simplify that.

Comment: Oh so you are saying $(a + bi)(-i) = -ai -bi^2$ where $i^2 = -1$ because it is a complex number so $-ai - b(-1) = -ai + b = b-ai$ wow thanks!

Comment: Oh so that means $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ is a eigenvector corr. to $\lambda = a + bi$ !

Answer (score 1):

Yusha, while working "backwards" is one way to show that the given is correct, it is more elegant to actually calculate the eigenvalues with eigenvectors. Here is how: Setting up the Characteristic equation, we get $(a-\lambda)^2+b^2=0$ which translates to $(a-\lambda)^2=i^2b^2$ .Solving gives $\lambda = a+/-bi$.  So let's first pick $\lambda=a+bi$. Now for this eigenvalue we wish to establish $ \begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$=$a+bi$ $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$. Working out through matrix multiplication we get $ax-by=ax+bix$, and $bx+ay=ay+bix$. Now terms $ax$ and $ay$ cancel. Observe that the remaining two equations are linear dependent (as they should be, why?), because they differ by a factor $i$. So $x$ is free, pick $x=1$ which results in $y=-i$ and so one corresponding eigenvector is found. For the other eigenvalue it goes the same way. You try.